# Alternate Cell Color in a column B for particular range say B67 to B323

Tags: vba, excel

I need to color alternate cells in a column in Excel via vb,basically requirement is if B1 value is selected like4/6/8/10/12 a table gets generated (done) and then with a particular pattern cells should be colored.I have done manually for few of them but requirement is to color alternate cells from B67:B323 in a column B.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service. See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for VBA for this.  Use conditional formatting instead.

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

`MOD(ROW(),2)` will return 1 for odd numbered rows, and 0 for even.

Comment: ++ Agreed. No VBA required